# Get yahoo comments with web scraping 2

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I am trying to extract all the comments of an article found on the yahoo news page using casperjs.
What I do first is to click on the "ver reacciones" button, then click on the response button of the first comments loaded to show the response comments.
So far, get the first comment and your answer, but I can not find the way to get all the answers of all the comments, in a few words, all the comments and the response comments found on the page.
Any algorithm that will help me get it?.
link: https://espanol.yahoo.com/noticias/el-fallo-de-orbita-del-supercohete-que-lanzaron-con-un-tesla-al-espacio-y-pasara-de-largo-marte-191841996.html

```
 //click button "ver reacciones"
 casper.waitForSelector('a.comments-title', function () {

    this.click('.comments-title');
});
//click button "ver mas"
casper.waitForSelector('button.showMore', function () {
    this.click('.showMore');
}
   , function onWaitTimeout() {
    //button does not exist
});

//click on "answer" buttons
var buttons;
casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list', function getLinks() {
buttons = this.evaluate(function ()
    {           
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('replies-button');
        buttons = Array.prototype.map.call(buttons, function (button) {
            button.click();      
            casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list', function () {                   
            });
            return button.getAttribute('class');
        });
        return buttons;
    });
}
, function onWaitTimeout() {

});

casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list > li', function () {  
    var x = this.getHTML('ul.comments-list');    
    this.echo(x);
   }
   , function onWaitTimeout() {        
});

casper.run();
```